# How to get internal kubernetes endpoint name with kubectl only?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, microk8s

How to use kubectl to obtain the internal endpoint name? Similar to the kubernetes dashboard.
Our production environment does not permit using of Dashboard. As an example,...This is needed for Helm3 Parameter to install kibana UI to point to ElasticSearch services in port 9200.

[Kubernetes Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shzxa.png)

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. An [endpoint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) is a resource that gets IP addresses of one or more pods dynamically assigned to it, along with a port. An endpoint can be viewed using
   **`kubectl get endpoints.`**
2. An endpoint resource is referenced by a kubernetes service, so that the service has a record of the internal IPs of pods in order to be able to communicate with them.

   ```
    $ kubectl get endpoints

   NAME          ENDPOINTS          AGE 
   kubernetes  192.168.64.13:8443   10d
   ```

Similar kubectl commands associated with endpoints:

**`kubectl describe pods`** - and observe the IP addresses of your pods

**`kubectl get ep`** - and observe the IP addresses assigned to your endpoint

**`kubectl describe service myServiceName`** - and observe the Endpoints associated with your service.

Refer to the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get) for more information on kubectl commands.

Comment: That is NOT the INTERNAL NAME as shown in my picture of the dashboard. All the command you shown only get partial service name. Not endpoint name.